# Seaborn plot with second y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

i wanted to know how to make a plot with two y-axis so that my plot that looks like this : [image]

to something more like this by adding another y-axis :
[image]

i'm only using this line of code from my plot in order to get the top 10 EngineVersions from my data frame :

```
sns.countplot(x='EngineVersion', data=train, order=train.EngineVersion.value_counts().iloc[:10].index);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1000,2000,500,8000,3000]
y1 = [1050,3000,2000,4000,6000]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.bar(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, y1, 'o-', color="red" )

ax1.set_xlabel('X data')
ax1.set_ylabel('Counts', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Detection Rates', color='b')

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: how do you do this with sns?

Comment: Might be too late for @gdubs, but just in case anyone's interested - you can use Seaborn (sns) to plot your graphs as usual, just create the new ax (ax2 = ax1.twinx()), then forward the appropriate Axes object to your Seaborn function using the 'ax' argument, for example:
ax1.bar(x, y) => sns.barplot(x=x, y=y, ax=ax1)
ax2.plot(x, y1, 'o-', color="red" ) => sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y1, color="red", ax=ax2)

Comment: @r02 +1 to your comment, thanks

Answer (score 14):

@gdubs If you want to do this with Seaborn's library, this code set up worked for me. Instead of setting the ax assignment "outside" of the plot function in matplotlib, you do it "inside" of the plot function in Seaborn, where `ax` is the variable that stores the plot.

```
import seaborn as sns # Calls in seaborn

# These lines generate the data to be plotted
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1000,2000,500,8000,3000]
y1 = [1050,3000,2000,4000,6000]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() # initializes figure and plots

ax2 = ax1.twinx() # applies twinx to ax2, which is the second y axis. 

sns.barplot(x = x, y = y, ax = ax1, color = 'blue') # plots the first set of data, and sets it to ax1. 
sns.lineplot(x = x, y = y1, marker = 'o', color = 'red', ax = ax2) # plots the second set, and sets to ax2. 

# these lines add the annotations for the plot. 
ax1.set_xlabel('X data')
ax1.set_ylabel('Counts', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Detection Rates', color='b')

plt.show(); # shows the plot.
```

Output:
[Seaborn output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Tpc.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code to obtain a very similar image to what you originally wanted.

```
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

x = ['1.1','1.2','1.2.1','2.0','2.1(beta)']
y = [1000,2000,500,8000,3000]
y1 = [3,4,1,8,5]
g = sb.barplot(x=x, y=y, color='blue')
g2 = sb.lineplot(x=range(len(x)), y=y1, color='orange', marker='o', ax=g.axes.twinx())
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=-30)
g.set_xlabel('EngineVersion')
g.set_ylabel('Counts')
g2.set_ylabel('Detections rate')
g.legend(handles=[Rectangle((0,0), 0, 0, color='blue', label='Nontouch device counts'), Line2D([], [], marker='o', color='orange', label='Detections rate for nontouch devices')], loc=(1.1,0.8))
```

[image]