# How to use secondary Y-axis for multiple subplots in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two data frame which has multiple columns. I have turned DataFrame into long-form using `pd.wide_to_long`

```
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df_1.reset_index(), ['dvr','r'], i='index', j='Sample ID').reset_index()
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df_2.reset_index(), ['dvlnr','r'], i='index', j='Sample ID').reset_index()
```

I want to create subplots and am inclined to use seaborn due to its elegant formatting features.
Here is my code to generate a subplot with secondary Y-Axis.

```
ax= sns.relplot(data=df1, x='r', y='dvlnr', col='Sample ID',  col_wrap=2, kind="line", height=4, aspect=1.5)
ax1 = plt.twinx()
ax1= sns.relplot(data=df2, x='r', y='dvr', ax=ax, col='Sample ID',  col_wrap=2, kind="line", height=4, aspect=1.5)
```

But I always get `ValueError: Could not interpret value 'dvr' for parameter 'y'`

I have checked a few examples [[eg1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654500/seaborn-plot-with-second-y-axis), [eg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591650/second-y-axis-time-series-seaborn) but I am able to figure out a solution as I am looking for multiple subplots with secondary Axis.
Is there any way to solve this? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you seem to be mixing `df1` and `df2`. Shouldn't you be using `y='dvlnr` only with `df2` (and vice versa)?

Another problem is that `sns.relplot` doesn't return an `ax`. Instead, it returns a `FacetGrid`. And for a FacetGrid you can't call `twinx()`. You'd need to catch the `FacetGrid` via `g = sns.relplot(data=df1, ...)` and loop through the axes, calling `twinx` on each of them and create individual scatterplots.  If the data ranges are similar enough, you could merge the dataframes and use `hue` to plot them in one go.

Here is some sample code for the case when the data ranges are too different to be plotted on the same y-axis:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'r': np.random.randint(1, 31, 200),
                    'dvr': np.random.uniform(100, 1000, 200),
                    'Sample ID': np.random.randint(1, 5, 200)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'r': np.random.randint(1, 31, 300),
                    'dvlnr': np.random.uniform(1, 10, 300),
                    'Sample ID': np.random.randint(1, 5, 300)})

g = sns.relplot(data=df1, x='r', y='dvr', col='Sample ID', col_wrap=2, kind="line", height=4, aspect=1.5,
                color='dodgerblue')

for sample_id, ax in g.axes_dict.items():  # axes_dict is new in seaborn 0.11.2
    ax1 = ax.twinx()
    sns.lineplot(data=df2[df2['Sample ID'] == sample_id], x='r', y='dvlnr', color='crimson', ax=ax1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: combining sns.relplot via ax.twinx()]

If the ranges of the y-data are similar enough, you can merge the dataframes and plot everything in one go using `hue=`. (This approach would also work with more dataframes.)

- a new column (e.g. 'source') needs to be added to indicate the original dataframe
- corresponding columns in both dataframes need the same name

Here is some example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'r1': np.random.randint(1, 31, 200),
                    'dvr1': np.random.uniform(100, 1000, 200),
                    'Sample ID': np.random.randint(1, 5, 200)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'r1': np.random.randint(1, 31, 300),
                    'dvlnr1': np.random.uniform(300, 1200, 300),
                    'Sample ID': np.random.randint(1, 5, 300)})

# add an extra column to tell to which df the data belongs
df1['source'] = 'dvr'
# the corresponding columns in both df need to have the same name for the merge
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'dvlnr1': 'dvr1'})
df2['source'] = 'dvrnr'
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index()

g = sns.relplot(data=df_merged, x='r1', y='dvr1', hue='source', col='Sample ID', col_wrap=2,
                kind="line", height=4, aspect=1.5, palette='turbo')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.06, left=0.06)  # plt.tight_layout() doesn't work due to legend
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.relplot with hue on newly created column for merged dfs]

Comment: Dear @JohanC, Data ranges are the same, but each data frame has multiple columns eg. for `df1: dvlnr1, r1, dvlr2, r2... ` same is the case with `df2: dvr1, r1;   dvr2, r2`.... But `r` columns of both the data frame is identical(same). If I merge it will look like `df_new=dvr1, dvlnr1, r1; dvr2, dvlr2, r2....goes upto 26`. Though you have answered the question, Could you please tell me how can I achieve this using `hue`  to plot them in one go?  Thanks for the answer.